# No gear option for X11/Xorg on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 23.04

No gear option for x11/Xorg on ubuntu 23.04
Ubuntu only boots in wayland and it's choppy and unstable.

Tried adding this on conf

`WaylandEnable=false`

It stopped booting got stuck in black screen and on that screen keyboard also didn't work (capslock and numlock keys did nothing) so can't switch to tty.

Tried installing lightdm and sddm.
They both didn't boot got stuck in black screen and same keyboard didn't work in any of those so can't switch to tty.

had to boot in recovery mode to set gdm3 as default, then only ubuntu boots.

is there any option to get Xorg running in ubuntu or do i have to switch to another distro ?

```
currently on nvidia-driver-545
Also tried downgrading driver
GPU : RTX 2060
CPU : i5 8400
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Nvidia site , you'll need the Version    535.129.03 for your driver. [Infos here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/213194/en-us/).

I'm using an older Nvidia Card myself - you'll need to check the correct version so it'll work. Try to download it via the Hardware tab - the drivers have to be compiled against your kernel, downloading from a 3rd party site usually won't work